# NLog config not reading boolean Property

Tags: logging, nlog, nlog-configuration

I have the following NLog filter (logger outputs to the DB):

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="Database" >
  <filters>
    <when condition="${event-properties:item=LogToDatabase} == false" action="Ignore"/>
  </filters>
</logger>
```

And that is how I call NLog:

```
Log.Error().Message("test").Property("LogToDatabase", false).Write();
```

The config seems to be not working with the bool values, however the only way I have managed to make it work is using strings in the config like this:

```
<when condition="'${event-properties:item=LogToDatabase}' == 'False'" action="Ignore"/>
```

Then calling NLog with a string Property:

```
Log.Error().Message("test").Property("LogToDatabase", false.ToString()).Write();
```

Is there a way to have a boolean check in the config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout Renderers in NLog only renders as **text**.
You can see code for event-properties here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/e0650c42b4ab3660abc60717e50535d20763289c/src/NLog/LayoutRenderers/EventPropertiesLayoutRenderer.cs

So you can not check NLog expressions as bool.

Comment: Can format be used to somehow set the type to Boolean like the DateTime is shown in the example?

Comment: Format can be used for additional formatting. But the result is text.

Comment: You also can write custom condition method that evaluates to bool.
Example: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=myrandom&type=

Standard condition methods: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/19de4feb0a6f1292e9d0c69da5c75b73efda3ea1/src/NLog/Conditions/ConditionMethods.cs

Comment: Custom condition looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: just a short question... if bools do not translate properly in NLog expressions, what do they translate into? Do they stay as objects (.Property(object, object))?

Comment: They stay objects but renders as string with some format and culture